# Why are Unix applications documented with an number in parenthesis with man?

Tags: linux, unix, man

When I try to get help on a Unix command, I get reference to say `tar(1)` or `lsof(8)`.

Why is there a number within parenthesis and what does it refer to exactly ?

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate, but I can't find the dup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The manual is divided into chapters and some topics are actually documented twice, which is often the case when there is a C library function or system call that is also available as a user space command or a config file is available with the same name as the command it documents (example: `chown` is a user space command and a system call and you find `chown` in section 1 and 2). The number is then used to select the appropriate chapter:

```
man 1 ls
```

- Section 1: user commands
- Section 2: system calls
- Section 3: library functions
- Section 4: special files
- Section 5:   file formats
- Section 6:     games
- Section 7:     conventions and miscellany
- Section 8:     administration and privileged commands
- Section L:     math library functions
- Section N:    tcl functions

Comment: Man page section layouts also vary between implementations as well, with the numbering and ordering differing slightly between System V Unix, Solaris, and Linux distros. Some man pages have additional sections depending on if an installed package or program also installs its man pages.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, what SvW said. You can get the full doc from man itself by typing:

```
$ man 1 man

   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro  packages  and  conven-
       tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```